# Slow LAN connection (especially receiving) on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, performance, lan, iperf

I was diagnosing my SMB performance issues when I noticed my whole network speed was off. These are my benchmarking results between my desktop and my Linux server:

Both are connected using CAT6 and have gigabit networking.

```
~$ iperf -c 192.168.2.10 -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.10, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  110 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 192.168.2.2 port 54320 connected with 192.168.2.10 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   114 MBytes  95.2 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.2.2 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.10 port 49719
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   532 MBytes   446 Mbits/sec
```

So, that's 446 Mb/s from my desktop to my server, and no more than 95 Mb/s from my server to my desktop, where both values should be (close to) 1000 Mb/s.

I recall getting >900 Mb/s in both directions when I was still running Windows 7.

I already tried all sorts of things, like turning off different offloading features in the NIC driver, manually downloading the latest NIC driver from Realtek and disabling autotuning using `netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled`.

**EDIT:**

I did some extensive testing with iperf between the switches and such in the way between my Linux server (LARS-ILLIUM) and my desktop (LARS-VIGIL). LARS-FEROS and LARS-RANNOCH are both switches, and the connection is as follows:

LARS-ILLIUM <---> LARS-FEROS <---> LARS-RANNOCH <---> LARS-VIGIL

Of course there are other devices connected to the switches, but this is the path between LARS-ILLIUM and LARS-VIGIL.

I made table of iperf results:
http://prntscr.com/39r0eh
I guess the table is fairly self-explainatory, but the first three rows are test results from left to right, and the bottom three rows are the other way around.
All tests were UDP btw. Complete command: `iperf -c 192.168.2.x -u -b 1000M`

Now I know that the problem isn't limited to my desktop LARS-VIGIL, but happens in the rest of my LAN as well. Still haven't a single clue what's happening though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason for the weird iperf results, was that every system I tested on has different default TCP window and UDP buffer sizes. After setting those manually with the -w option I get consistent results:

```
C:\Users\Lars Veldscholte\Downloads\iperf>iperf -c 192.168.2.2 -w 416k -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  416 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  416 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.2.10 port 55803 connected with 192.168.2.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  1003 MBytes   841 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.2.10 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.2 port 45938
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   863 MBytes   724 Mbits/sec
```

At least, between my server (LARS-ILLIUM) and my desktop (LARS-VIGIL). Testing on the switches in between still yields weird results:

```
C:\Users\Lars Veldscholte\Downloads\iperf>iperf -c 192.168.2.1 -w 320k -r
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  320 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  320 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.2.10 port 55833 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.3 sec  9.12 MBytes  7.43 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.2.10 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 55335
[  4]  0.0-10.4 sec  5.00 MBytes  4.01 Mbits/sec
```

I don't know what's up with that.